I there an API to get ad_account_id or campaign_id from Facebook post Id?
I've scoured through Graph API documents and their community forums, but I failed to find what I'm looking for.
I have page_id and post_id of a post that's an ad on Facebook, and I'd like to know the ad_account_id that is used to advertise it, or at least the campaign_id that the post belongs to.
I know the other way around that I could get post id from tracking_specs fields in act_<ad_account_id> endpoint, but is there anyway to get it backward?
Thank you in advance.
